# Grep or awk between 2 large files where file1 is a pattern file and file2 contains the data

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

`File1` has numbers of fixed length, with one number in each row.:

```
1234
5678
1345
```

`File2` contains data fields in "key=value" format:

```
abc:def=1999,xyz=1234;
abc:def=5678,xyz=1234;
abc:def=1234,xyz=5678;
```

I need to get those lines of `File2` where the `def` field matches any number in `File1`, but the `xyz` field is ignored for pattern match. So, my result should look like:

```
abc:def=5678,xyz=1234;
abc:def=1234,xyz=5678;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collect the numbers into a hash (`nums` in this case), and use it for convenient lookup later:

```
awk -F '[=,;]' 'FNR==NR { nums[$1]; next } $2 in nums' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
abc:def=5678,xyz=1234;
abc:def=1234,xyz=5678;
```

In case the order of the fields is not constant, something like this would work:

```
awk -F'[=,;:]' '
  FNR==NR { nums[$1]; next }
  $2 == "def" && ($3 in nums) || $4 == "def" && ($5 in nums)
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 7):

I always forget most `awk` commands, too much for my old brain, so I offer an `sed` alternative

```
sed '/^[0-9]*$/H;G;/def=\([0-9]*\),.*\n\1/P;d' file1 file2
```

The idea is to collect the numbers of `file1` in hold space and use a backreference to identify those lines of file2 that contain such a number as `def=`

- The pattern `^[0-9]*$` matches lines with only digits, which are `file1` lines and we append it to `H`old space
- `G` appends the hold space to pattern space, so we have the `file2` lines and all n umbers from `file1` in pattern space
- The pattern `/def=\([0-9]*\),.*\n\1` addresses all lines where the number after `def=` is repeated (backreference `\1`) after a newline (so it was part of the hold space collection). `P`rint those lines without the appended stuff
- `d` suppresses further output. You could use option `-n` instead

**Update: visual explanation**

As Ed points out my explanation is obviously not helpful for everybody. If you are more a "visual thinker", I'll try to illustrate the principle. Keep in mind that `sed` is no programming tool, but more like an automated text editor with the *hold space* as "clipboard", while the lines are read into the *pattern space*, where work is done.

Now I follow the suggestion to show both spaces after the `H` and `G` commands:

| pattern space | hold space | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1234` | ␤`1234` | the `H` appends to the (empty) hold space with an embedded newline |
| `1234`␤␤`1234` | ␤`1234` | the `G` appends back to the pattern space, adding another newline |
| `5678` | ␤`1234`␤`5678` | the hold space is kept while the next line is read so the next `H` appends the next number |
| `5678`␤␤`1234`␤`5678` | ␤`1234`␤`5678` | again appending back to pattern space, but still no match for the `def=` pattern |
|  |  | skipping the third line of `file1` for readability |
| `abc:def=1999,xyz=1234;` | ␤`1234`␤`5678` | no match with pattern `^[0-9]*$`, so `H` is not executed |
| `abc:def=1999,xyz=1234;`␤␤`1234`␤`5678` | ␤`1234`␤`5678` | but `G` is executed |

Now see how the address pattern for the `P` command is applied (using `\n` as placeholder for newline):

```
abc:def=1999,xyz=1234;\n\n1234\n5678
    def=####,         .*                 #### stands for `[0-9]*`, but the back reference
                                         as `\1` is not found: no match

abc:def=5678,xyz=1234;\n\n1234\n5678
    def=####,         .*      \n####     here, the match is repeated as `\1`,so we know
                                         the `def` number has been listed in `file1`
```

Comment: Even after reading the explanation multiple times I can't visualize what that script is doing. I think I'd need pictures of the "hold space" and "pattern space" before and after each command (H, G) and the /def=.../ match to stand a chance (probably drawn in crayon).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your suggestion but not sure why it wasnt giving me any result, i tried what Thor suggested below and it worked.

Comment: @Tee-ess No idea; I tested it with the samples you provided and it worked. Anyhow: You found a solution, so I suppose we don't need to find out the problem?

Comment: @EdMorton Is this explanation better? I know the question is answered, but I like to improve my didactics

Comment: @Philippos that was very helpful, thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
grep -f <(sed 's/^/abc:def=/' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

or you can create a new file if your shell doesn't support `<()`:

```bsh
sed 's/^/abc:def=/' file1.txt > patterns.txt
grep -f patterns.txt file2.txt
```

or you can create a fifo file:

```bsh
mkfifo fifo
sed 's/^/abc:def=/' file1.txt >fifo &
grep -f fifo file2.txt
```

Comment: It's useful in two large files I think.